# How to solve $\int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(wx) \, dx=\frac a {a^2+w^2}$ with using Fourier transform?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

$\int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(wx) \, dx=\frac{a}{a^2+w^2}$
I thought it is Fourier sine transform of $f(x)$

since  $\ F_s(f(x))=F_s(k)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \int_0^\infty f(x)\sin(wx) \, dx$

so $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} F_s(w)=\frac{a}{a^2+w^2}$. by taking invers sin transform of this

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{a}{a^2+w^2} \sin(wx)\,dx$$

Comment: One approach would be to let $f(x) = e^{-ax}$ and see what happens.

Comment: The variable of integration on the right should be $w$ instead of $x$.

Comment: Usually, you are allowed to use a table of transforms...

Comment: @WW1: er, what ??

Comment: I wonder if you're copying from some source that uses the letter $\omega$ rather than the letter $w. \qquad$

Comment: I dont understand what is wrong with the question. It is from Lokenath's integral transform and application book. https://i.ibb.co/k8nrNjk/dam.png

Comment: If what you've done is correct so far, you could pull the fraction $\frac{a}{a^2+w^2}$ out of the integral since they don't depend on x.  That just leaves you with the integral of $sin(wx)$, so which is indeterminant with the upper limit of infinity, so that makes me think you've done something wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what I mean is $$ \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{a}{a^2+w^2} \sin(wx)\,dw $$

Comment: assuming $f(x)$ does not depend on $w$
$$F(w) \equiv \int_0^\infty f(x) \sin(wx) \, dx$$
is an odd function of $w$, but
$$\frac a {a^2+w^2}$$
is even in $w$, perhaps there is a typo in the question and the rhs should really be
$$\frac w {a^2+w^2}$$

Comment: @WW1 the fourier sine transform is not defined for $w<0$, so there is no restriction on  the parity of $F(w)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be clear to those who have dealt with Laplace transforms. The Laplace transform of $\sin wt$ is given by ${w \over w^2 + s^2}$. In other words
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-st} \sin wt \,dt = {w \over w^2 + s^2}$$
Thus in your notation, the answer to your question is ${a \over w} e^{-ax}$.

Comment: I do not understand why this answer has been accepted when it doesn't match the form given in the statement of the problem. This would be correct if the statement was $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\sin\omega x=\frac{\omega}{s^2+\omega^2}$ or if the function $f$ was allowed to depend on $\omega$. If this is about the sine transform there's no way it can depend on it- also it is nowhere stated above that it does.

Comment: $x$ is just the variable of integration, I just called it $t$ because that's the terminology normally used in Laplace transforms. For a fixed value of $a$, the answer will be a function of $w$, and therefore the final answer will have both $a$ and $w$ in it. Your answer too is a function of both $a$ and $w$ by the way.

Comment: If you look at my answer carefully you will realize that it is a function only of $x,a$ in OP's notation while yours contains all three $x, w, a$ so I believe very different.

Answer (score 0):

Upon second thought, there seems to be nothing wrong with this question. In fact, if one restricts the domain of the FST to $\omega>0$, the transform has a unique inverse, which should exist as long as $f$ is absolutely integrable. Indeed it can be shown that the inverse defined by

$$F^{-1}_s\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}dxf(x)\sin{\omega x}\right](\omega)=\frac{2a}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\omega t}{t^2+a^2}dt$$

converges absolutely and therefore it is equal to $f(\omega)$. This integral can only be done in terms of special functions. One can compute that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-zx}}{x^2+a^2}dx=\int_{\infty}^{z}\frac{\sin a (z-z')}{z'}dz'=\frac{\sin az}{a}\text{Ci}(az)+\frac{\cos az }{a}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\text{Si}(az)\right), ~~\text{Re}~z\geq 0$$

where the last equality is given in terms of the cosine-sine integrals. We can set therefore $z=\pm i\omega $ in the expression above to get the final result

$$\frac{\pi}{2a}f(\omega)=\frac{\cosh a\omega}{a}\frac{\text{Si}(ia\omega)-\text{Si}(-ia\omega)}{2i}-\frac{\sinh a\omega}{a}\frac{\text{Ci}(ia\omega)+\text{Ci}(-ia\omega)}{2}$$

which converges for all $\omega>0$.